# How do I read "off of" naturally?

Tags: pronunciation

> He brushes a lock of hair **off of** my cheek.

Either I should make a break between "off" and "of" or read them linked "offov"?

Answer (score 1):

Either way is normal. The elided *offov* form is more common when the speaker is speaking relatively fast.

Note that you don't really need the *of* for the sentence to be grammatical:

> He brushes a lock of hair off my cheek.